# How can use edit form only post method using cakePHP 2.x?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.x. When I submit an edit form it not work for following code:

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post'))) {
    ...

    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

But it work for following code:

```
if ($this->request->is(array('post','put'))) { //change made here
    ...

    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ...
}
```

But I want my code work only for first code. Please help me if you have any solution.

**EDIT :**
Note that, when we create a from using CakePHP each time it's create a hidden input variable name **_method** which value set **POST** on add form and **PUT** on edit form. CakePHP request handler work with **_method** variable, not on form type attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Add the option 'type' => 'post' when creating your form, and I believe it will always use post as its method.  Example:

```
 echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('type' => 'post'));
```

Comment: It's working now. But when I use 'type' = > 'file', then it's not working.

Comment: Why should it? `file` is not a valid HTTP request method.

Comment: Specifying ‘file’ changes the form submission method to ‘post’, and includes an enctype of “multipart/form-data” on the form tag. This is to be used if there are any file elements inside the
form. The absence of the proper enctype attribute will cause the file uploads not to function:

    <?php echo $this->Form->create(’User’, array(’type’ => ’file’)); ?>

Output:
    <form id="UserEditForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/users/add">

Answer (score 0):

Cakephp overwrites POST with PUT request method when you create form with type=>file.
You have to check it with

```
if($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('post')) {
}
```